# Writing a program that inputs a three digit number to output the digits on a single line

Tags: python

I am writing a program on python that will allow the user to input any three digit number and will output the number as separate digits.

This is what I have right now

```
val = int(raw_input ("Type your three digit number please:"))

print 'The first digit is {}' .format (val // 100)
print 'The second digit is {}'.format (val % 100)
print 'The third digit is {}'.format (val % 10)`
```

However, for the the second digit I am not sure how to retrieve that. I know the number should not be 100 as it returns the last two digits to me then.

Can someone please help me?

Also does anyone know how I would then proceed to adding the digits up?

Comment: Do you want to show the digits entered or do math with it?

Comment: I just want to show the digits.

For example, if the user entered 678

the program will then output print statements such as

The first digit is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
val = raw_input("Type your three digit number please: ")

print 'The first digit is {}'.format(val[0])
print 'The second digit is {}'.format(val[1])
print 'The third digit is {}'.format(val[2])
```

Changing the input from `str` to `int` will make digits impossible to separate, if you still want the input as integer you can wrap a `int()` around the `val[]`, like `int(val[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to not treat is as an `int`, I'd think:

```
digits = raw_input("Type your three digit number please")
print(list(digits)) # will print ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
val = raw_input ("Type your three digit number please:")#you must type 12 13 14
val=val+" "
list=[]
s=""
for i in val:
    if i!=" ":
        s=s+i
    else:
        list.append(int(s))
        s=""
print list
```

output is

```
[12,13,14]
```