# Adding the sum of three digits

Tags: python

So I am writting a program that inputs a 3 # digit and breaks it apart. I am having trouble figuring out how to then add the separate digits altogether?

For example: The user inputs 345

My program will break the #'s apart to 3,4,5 but how do I then add those numbers together?

this is my code thus far,

```
#set variable
val = raw_input("Type your three digit number please: ")


print 'The first digit is {}'.format(val[0])
print 'The second digit is {}'.format(val[1])
print 'The third digit is {}'.format(val[2])


#set variable
total = [val[0] +val [1] + val[2]]
total_value = total

print 'The sum of the three digits is' total_value
```

Comment: Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15566019/939986) to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15565656/939986) carefully.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Indeed!  Why the same question twice? Sounds like desperation to get some homework done. :D

Answer (score 6):

A short way to add all of the number's digits together is:

```
In [3]: sum(map(int, val))
Out[3]: 12
```

Here, `map(int, val)` iterates over the characters of `val` and converts each of them into an `int`, and `sum(...)` adds together all those `int`s.

The nice thing about this approach is that it works for any number of digits.

The reason your original code doesn't work is that `val[0]` etc are *strings*, so using `+` simply concatenates those strings back together. To add the numeric values, you would have to convert the characters to `int` first:

```
In [5]: int(val[0]) + int(val[1]) + int(val[2])
Out[5]: 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert the individual components to numbers to be able to add them:

```
total = int(val[0]) + int(val[1]) + int(val[2])
```

Or, more concise:

```
total = sum(int(x) for x in val)
```

Comment: No need to create a `list` here... Just keep it as `int(x) for ...`

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution is to use python's builtin functions [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
val = raw_input("Type your three digit number please: ")
total = sum(map(int, val))
print 'The sum of the three digits is', total
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do this :

```
total = int(val[0]) + int(val[1]) + int(val[2])
```

Since the digits in `val` are characters, they have to be converted to integers first.
Note that there are no `[ ]` around the value affected to `total` as in your code (you don't want a list, you want a single value).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
res = raw_input("Enter value: ")
print sum(map(int, res))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer you looking for is something like this:

```
a = int(input("3 digit number:"))
x = a // 100
y = a // 10 % 10
z = a % 10
print (x + y + z)
```

i'm a total noob and its an ez question for noobs learning but when looking for an ez answer i couldn't find it anywhere ([here](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-68.php)) The question is Adding the sum of "THREE" digits...
I got hung up on if the digits were 5 or 6 long dunno what the code would look like if digits weren't defined.

answer:

```
a = int(input("enter a few numbers:"))
conversion = str(a)
number =[]
for i in conversion:
    a = int(i)
    number.append(a)
print (sum(number))
```

or as shown before me:

```
number = map(int, str(input('Enter a number: ')))
print(sum(number))
```

but i still have a ways to goes till i understand this properly